# How to do a Masked label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to perform a mask on a label , How Can I do that ?

I've tried to use RadMaskedTextbox but the problem is that if I disable that control the text is Gray And I need it to be red

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make a textbox disabled but retain coloration, use the readonly property instead of disabling it.

Comment: also make back color transparent, and turn off style, it will look like an label :)